# ¿Cómo centrar todos los datos de una columna en un JTable? - Java

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo el siguiente método que se encarga de cargar los datos a la tabla:

```
@Override
public void bioquimicosHabilitadosObtenidos(final List<Cuenta> cuentas) {
    final String[] columnas = {"Nº", "CODIGO CUENTA", "CODIGO PERSONA", "C.I", "APELLIDO", "NOMBRE", "SEXO", "CODIGO BIOQUIMICO", "PROFESION", "FECHA INICIO", "HORA INICIO", "BIOQUIMICO HABILITADO", "CUENTA CLAVE", "CUENTA ROL", "CUENTA FECHA REGISTRO", "CUENTA HORA REGISTRO", "CUENTA ESTADO"};
    final String[][] datos = construirMatrizCuentasBioquimicosHabilitados(cuentas);
    final DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(datos, columnas);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.setModel(defaultTableModel);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.setRowHeight(20);
    
    TableColumnModel tableColumnModel = JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel();
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(1));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(1));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(5));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(8));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(8));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(8));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(8));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(8));
    tableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumnModel.getColumn(8));
    
    final DefaultTableCellRenderer defaultTableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer();
    defaultTableCellRenderer.setHorizontalTextPosition(defaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(defaultTableCellRenderer);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(defaultTableCellRenderer);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(defaultTableCellRenderer);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(defaultTableCellRenderer);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(defaultTableCellRenderer);
    
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(10);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(40);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(10);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(150);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(70);
    JTBLBioquimicosActivos.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(70);
    
   }
```

Este es el otro método para cargar los datos a la matriz `datos`:

```
private String[][] construirMatrizCuentasBioquimicosHabilitados(final List<Cuenta> cuentas) {
    final String[][] matrizDatos = new String[cuentas.size()][17];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrizDatos.length; i++) {
        final Bioquimico bioquimico = cuentas.get(i).getBioquimico();
        final Persona persona = bioquimico.getPersona();
        matrizDatos[i][0] = String.valueOf(i+1);
        matrizDatos[i][1] = String.valueOf(cuentas.get(i).getCodigoCuenta());
        matrizDatos[i][2] = String.valueOf(persona.getCodigoPersona());
        matrizDatos[i][3] = persona.getPersonaCedulaIdentidad();
        matrizDatos[i][4] = persona.getPersonaApellido();
        matrizDatos[i][5] = persona.getPersonaNombre();
        matrizDatos[i][6] = persona.getPersonaSexo();
        matrizDatos[i][7] = String.valueOf(bioquimico.getCodigoBioquimico());
        matrizDatos[i][8] = bioquimico.getBioquimicoProfesion();
        matrizDatos[i][9] = bioquimico.getBioquimicoFechaInicio();
        matrizDatos[i][10] = bioquimico.getBioquimicoHoraInicio();
        matrizDatos[i][11] = bioquimico.getBioquimicoHabilitado()? "1" : "0";
        matrizDatos[i][12] = cuentas.get(i).getCuentaClave();
        matrizDatos[i][13] = cuentas.get(i).getCuentaRol();
        matrizDatos[i][14] = cuentas.get(i).getCuentaFechaRegistro();
        matrizDatos[i][15] = cuentas.get(i).getCuentaHoraRegistro();
        matrizDatos[i][16] = String.valueOf(cuentas.get(i).getCuentaEstado());
    }
    return matrizDatos;
}
```

La clase `Cuenta`:

```
public class Cuenta {

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Variables">

    private int codigoCuenta;
    private Bioquimico bioquimico;
    private String cuentaClave;
    private String cuentaRol;
    private String cuentaFechaRegistro;
    private String cuentaHoraRegistro;
    private int cuentaEstado;

    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Constructor">

    public Cuenta(int codigoCuenta, Bioquimico bioquimico, String cuentaClave, String cuentaRol, String cuentaFechaRegistro, String cuentaHoraRegistro, int cuentaEstado) {
        this.codigoCuenta = codigoCuenta;
        this.bioquimico = bioquimico;
        this.cuentaClave = cuentaClave;
        this.cuentaRol = cuentaRol;
        this.cuentaFechaRegistro = cuentaFechaRegistro;
        this.cuentaHoraRegistro = cuentaHoraRegistro;
        this.cuentaEstado = cuentaEstado;
    }

    public Cuenta(Bioquimico bioquimico, String cuentaClave, String cuentaRol, int cuentaEstado) {
        this.bioquimico = bioquimico;
        this.cuentaClave = cuentaClave;
        this.cuentaRol = cuentaRol;
        this.cuentaEstado = cuentaEstado;
    }

    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Getters and Setters">

    public int getCodigoCuenta() {
        return codigoCuenta;
    }

    public void setCodigoCuenta(int codigoCuenta) {
        this.codigoCuenta = codigoCuenta;
    }

    public Bioquimico getBioquimico() {
        return bioquimico;
    }

    public void setBioquimico(Bioquimico bioquimico) {
        this.bioquimico = bioquimico;
    }

    public String getCuentaClave() {
        return cuentaClave;
    }

    public void setCuentaClave(String cuentaClave) {
        this.cuentaClave = cuentaClave;
    }

    public String getCuentaRol() {
        return cuentaRol;
    }

    public void setCuentaRol(String cuentaRol) {
        this.cuentaRol = cuentaRol;
    }

    public String getCuentaFechaRegistro() {
        return cuentaFechaRegistro;
    }

    public void setCuentaFechaRegistro(String cuentaFechaRegistro) {
        this.cuentaFechaRegistro = cuentaFechaRegistro;
    }

    public String getCuentaHoraRegistro() {
        return cuentaHoraRegistro;
    }

    public void setCuentaHoraRegistro(String cuentaHoraRegistro) {
        this.cuentaHoraRegistro = cuentaHoraRegistro;
    }

    public int getCuentaEstado() {
        return cuentaEstado;
    }

    public void setCuentaEstado(int cuentaEstado) {
        this.cuentaEstado = cuentaEstado;
    }

    // </editor-fold>

}
```

Quiero centrar las columnas: `Nº`, `C.I`, `SEXO`, `FECHA INICIO`, `HORA INICIO`, y como resultado obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que las columnas que quiero centrar están adoptando la misma apariencia que el encabezado de la tabla y yo deseo que tenga la apariencia de las columnas: `APELLIDO`, `NOMBRE`, `PROFESION`.

Comment: Lo siento, pero tu código no compila, esto se debe a que la variable datos se incializa con un método que no incluiste. Para conseguir ayuda más puntual simplifica tu problema con los datos mínimos para reproducirlo, a esto se le llama [mcve]

Comment: El problema no es como cargar los datos, eso lo podrías haber hecho declarando tus propios datos en una matriz, de todos modos si lo necesitas ya agregue el método.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativo porque el Ejemplo que proporcionaste no es fácil de reproducir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4747/342)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas tu objeto de celdas lo inicializas como encabezado

```
final DefaultTableCellRenderer defaultTableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer();
```

Por eso tiene esa forma, cambialo a

```
final DefaultTableCellRenderer defaultTableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
```

Comment: Ahhh cierto, verdad, no me había dado cuenta, todo por hacer `CTRL` + `ESPACE` + `ENTER`.....Gracias.